# How to create a multi-series funnel chart with AmCharts (or other chart libraries)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, visualization, amcharts

I am trying to create a funnel chart with multiple series using AmCharts (or any other chart library). Specifically, I want to display multiple funnel values within an existing funnel, as shown in this image.

[image]

Tried to come up with a concept from this pen here -> https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/abWVPeo and tried to combine the dataseries within by looking at their docs. It seems that when creating two dataseries, it aggregates them into the same chart, but I'm unaware of any syntax from within their docs that allows you to display multiple values in the same chart (like you would for a bar chart / line chart)

```
// Codepen code
// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(
  am5percent.FunnelSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    valueField: "applicants",
    categoryField: "stage",
    orientation: "vertical",
  })
);
series.data.setAll(data);
series.labels.template.set("visible", false);

var series2 = chart.series.push(
  am5percent.PyramidSeries.new(root, {
    name: "Series",
    valueField: "applicants",
    categoryField: "stage",
    orientation: "vertical",
  })
);
series2.data.setAll(data);
series2.labels.template.set("visible", false);
```

I have searched the entire AmCharts documentation, but couldn't find anything that matches this concept. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this with AmCharts, or recommend another chart library that can support this functionality? Any help would be greatly appreciated.